# How to connect a bridge to a tunnel with netplan?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, bridge, tunneling, netplan

Well, before I asked this question, I searched a lot and couldn't find a proper answer (or the question was wrongly asked).

I want to connect a bridge to a GRE tunnel on netplan.
I can successfully do the connection, but the routing table doesn't get updated correctly. I am forced to add the route manually for it to work.

So, here's my netplan setup:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        enp1s0f0:
            dhcp4: no
            accept-ra: false
            addresses:
            - 192.168.0.100/24
            routes:
                - to: default
                  via: 192.168.0.254
            match:
                macaddress: d8:5e:d3:43:cd:ae
            set-name: enp1s0f0
            nameservers:
               addresses:
                   - 1.1.1.1
                   - 1.0.0.1
                   - 2606:4700:4700::1111
                   - 2606:4700:4700::1001
    tunnels:
        gre1:
            mode: gre
            remote: 192.168.100.150
            local: 192.168.0.100
    bridges:
        br1:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            optional: true
            interfaces: [ gre1 ]
            addresses:
                - 172.16.20.2/30
            routes:
                - to: default
                  via: 172.16.20.1
                  scope: link
                  table: 100
            routing-policy:
                - from: 172.16.20.0/30
                  table: 100
```

With the above configuration, the gre1 has a state UNKNOWN and the br1 state is DOWN.
If I try to ping 172.16.20.1 it fails.

But, if I run:
`ip route add 172.16.20.0/30 dev gre1`
I can ping without any issues.

Anyone has a clue on how to solve this riddle?